# How can I upload large media file in S3 from client side?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I have a form where a user submits an image from the client-side. Currently, I am using AWS amplify to upload images to s3. I have not faced an issue so far because most of the times users selected the images less than 5MB. But right now I need to expand this limit and also optimizes the performance as well because the size limit is increased. When I have researched into performance, I got to know about the transfer acceleration and its compatibility with AWS SDK but not AWS amplify. So, I had to move my upload logic to SDK. The architecture I am following in the backend is Serverless and Lambda's. Let's say the user submits his form, the request cycle contains the image of size 10MB. But lambda will not process this request because the lambda request-response cycle is limited to 6MB transactions. How can I improve the performance, along with increasing the size limit? Also, can it be achieved with the AWS amplify itself?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is best served with S3 pre-signed urls. In this case your lambda function generates a url using the aws-sdk for a s3 upload and give back only the url for your frontend. Then you can upload directly to this url from the frontend without AWS Lambda being invoked again. All the data transfer will occur between your frontend and S3.

You can find more details about this solution [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).